# How to check return value of fileURL(withPath:) for failure?

Tags: ios, swift, return-value, filepath

I'm converting some Objective-C code to Swift.  The Objective-C looks like:

```
NSURL *urlPathForScans = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sDirIn];
if (nil != urlPathForScans) { 
    // some code…
```

and I have converted that code to this:

```
var urlPathForScans = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: sDirIn)
if urlPathForScans != nil  {
    // some code …
```

which gives me the following warning when I build:

> Comparing non-optional value of type 'URL' to 'nil' always returns true

The Swift docs for [`NSURL.fileURL(withPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1410828-fileurl) do not suggest in any way that the return value could indicate failure, even though clearly the supplied path parameter could be invalid. How to properly check the return value here for failure in case `sDirIn` is not a valid path?

Comment: Note that the behaviour in Swift is no different than the behaviour in Objective-C. Checking for `nil` in Objective-C wouldn't have done very much either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this method is not supposed to ever fail. The check in the Objective-C code is redundant. You will need to perform a check for `nil` later when trying to fetch a file through this url.

Comment: Thanks.  Just fyi the url will be used to write files.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift `fileURLWithPath` returns a non-optional which cannot be `nil`

And please use native `URL` rather than `NSURL`

```
let urlPathForScans = URL(fileURLWithPath: sDirIn)
```

You could check if the URL is valid

```
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: sDirIn) {

}
```

or

```
let urlIsValid = (try? urlPathForScans.checkResourceIsReachable()) ?? false
```